# R subset from Character class input

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, subset, shiny

I have a dataframe `st`:

```
Col | Val
d16 | 1
d17 | 1
d18 | 1
```

and I've used `paste0`, to get `p1<-paste0(st$c, "==", st$val, sep="&", collapse = "")`

which gives "d16==1&d17==1&d18==1&" and then created

`p2<-substr(p1, 1, nchar(p1)-1)` to get rid of the last `&` in p1.

The main reason for doing all of this, is that I have a bigger data set let's call it `ST`, which has columns `d16`, `d17`, and `d18` and I would like to subset `ST` with the following command:

```
ST <- subset(ST, p2)
```

However when I try that I get `Error in subset.data.frame(seg, p2) : 'subset' must be logical`

Which makes sense, `p2` must be of class LOGICAL and not class CHAR. I've tried using `as.logical`, I've tried converting it to a factor first, and using `as.logical`. But that didn't work. I've also tried using the `eval(parse(text=p2))` but no luck there either.

**How do I change `p2` so that it can used within `subset`?**

---

**Background:** 
I wanted to keep what I was trying to do simple, but I think it lead to more confusion so I want to explain why I'm even running into this issue.

What I'm really working on is a Shiny App. I have `ST` which looks something like

```
d16  d17  d18  t14  t15 t16 z15 z16 z20
1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1  1  0  0
2   1   0   0   1   0   0   0  0  1  0
3   0   1   0   1   1   0   1  1  1  1 
4   1   1   0   0   0   1   1  0  1  0
```

the names of the columns aren't that important, but `ST` essentially has many columns where each entry is either 1 or 0. Since there are many columns (100+), I want the user to pre-select which columns they'd like to make see the raw data for. My solution to this was to use Radio Buttons with '1', '0', or '2' for a no choice. Then I would take those inputs and make a vector of values: `val`, and combine that into a data frame with column names from `ST`, and then `st` comes from the columns that were selected:

```
val<-c(0,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2)
c<-colnames(ST)
test<-data.frame(c,val)
st<-subset(test, val==1)
```

Then I was trying to use

```
p1<-paste0(st$c, "==", st$val, sep="&", collapse = "")
p2<-substr(p1, 1, nchar(p1)-1)
```

So that I could take `p2` and enter it into a another `subset` function.

Comment: Can you add reproducible example of your data st?

Comment: You seem to be unwilling to simply type that expression into `subset`, in which case, stop trying to use `subset`. (And definitely don't use `eval(parse())`.) I might try making `st` into a data frame with columns `d16`, etc, and the doing a `dplyr::semi_join` with `ST`.

Comment: @joran, I actually did copy/paste the output of p2 and it worked. However I need a way to do this automatically. I'm going to add a bigger description of my thinking in the original post.

Comment: @suchait, st is pretty much exactly as I've show, but I will add a bigger description of my thinking in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doomed to stick with your approach, where indeed creating p2 as a rule-containing character string is already a step in the wrong direction, then you would probably really have to do something like...

```
# example
eval(parse(text = "Day == 1"), envir = airquality)

# your case
eval(parse(text = p2), envir = ST)
```

...to create a logical vector of indices that you can then even use in a simple `[` subscript

---

edit following comment, showing one possible alternative to character condition:

```
# assuming your st as above:
st <- data.frame(Col = c("d16", "d17", "d18"), Val = 1)

# transpose
st2 <- data.frame(t(st$Val))
colnames(st2) <- st$Col

st2
#  d16 d17 d18
#1   1   1   1

# merge (default arguments fit your case)
merge(ST, st2)
```

If you want, you can also convert your `data.frames` to `data.tables`, and perform the same `merge` on those. I.e. `data.table::setDT(ST)`, `data.table::setDT(st2)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. No, I wouldn't say I'm doomed or forced into this approach.

Answer (score 0):

What are you subsetting? should be the question. Remember we subset the rows in which the columns satisfy a certain condition. The condition given to `subset` function should involve the columns:

Lets take an example:

```
(dat=data.frame(d16=c(-1,1,1,3,4,5),d17=c(5,4,1,1,2,3),d18=1))
  d16 d17 d18
1  -1   5   1
2   1   4   1
3   1   1   1
4   3   1   1
5   4   2   1
6   5   3   1
```

This is our data: in the above data  we would like to get the row with `d16=1&d17=1&d18=1`. We might have a lot of variables thus we can use the paste method that you suggested:

```
subset(dat,eval(parse(text=paste0(ST$Col,"==",ST$Val,collapse = "&"))))
  d16 d17 d18
3   1   1   1
```

where the data frame `ST` is given as:

```
ST
   Col Val
1 d16    1
2 d17    1
3 d18    1
```

Your problem was in the data that you wanted to subset. With the correct data, you can do the subset.

Comment: As I've tested this more it seems to break down. I get errors like Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'd17' not found.

Comment: It depends whether there is d17 in your data. So how can you subset with no d17. Eg you have a data that has only d16 and d18 yet you want to subset it on the basis of d17..there is no d17in the data. So of course it will give you the error that there is no d17. Look at how I gave my data example and you will see that I do have a COLUMN d16, d17 and d18